# Ошибка платформы JUnit при запуске тестов

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, junit

При запуске отдельного теста выбрасывается ошибка
`Failed to resolve org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.7.0`

Но если запустить тестирование целого проекта через maven *(lifecycle -> test)* то подобной ошибки не видно, и все тесты спокойно срабатывают.

Для использования JUnit в зависимостях используется:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

У остальных людей которые работают на данном проекте (один репозиторий, разные ветки) подобных проблем не наблюдается. Что может вызывать данную ошибку?

UPD 1: используемая IDE - IntelliJ IDEA

**UPD 2**: Я все перепробовал. Удаление папки .idea не повлияло ни на что, равно как и повторная загрузка всех зависимостей. Очистка кеша также не дала результата. Прокси тоже указан.

Comment: Как запускаете отдельный тест?

Comment: Напрямую с IDE, нажимая на кнопку в виде зелёного треугольника, рядом с названием метода

Comment: Нужно в вопросе указать, какая IDE используется. Недостающую информацию (а ответы на эти вопросы таковой являются) нужно вносить в текст вопроса кнопкой "Править".

Comment: попробуйте сделать как тут советуют https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003256319-Exception-intellij-failed-to-resolve-org-junit-platform-junit-platform-launcher-1-3-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена путем ручного добавления файлов JUnit Platform Launcher в локальный репозиторий. Вероятно, это не является оптимальным решением, но оно сработало для меня